# Uploading files to IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I just wanted to ask is it possible to upload files to IIS server? If it's possible please describe me how to do it, thanks. I've been using google since 1h and i found nothing.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=asp.net+fileupload&oq=asp.net+fileupload&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2258j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Use VS? https://www.google.com/search?q=publish+asp.net+website&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta&channel=sb

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is file upload to your web server, you could set up FTP on your server 
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7

If you are looking for a file upload capability for your web application, you can use the [FileUpload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The file would be POSTed to your page once you submit your form. The MSDN page has a an example of how to use the control and save the file on the server side.

Comment: Mmhm... I didn't specified my issue good i think. I need to create site using ASP.net and upload files from this site to server. Is is even possible?

Comment: Then you can use the FileUpload control, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a web application that has file upload capability
- Host the web application in IIS.

Files uploaded will be dropped in your applications folder.

Take a look at for an example of file upload with WebApi: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx